# Finding Conditional Distribution from Poisson Distribution

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

> A system receives shocks according to a Poisson process with rate $λ$. Each shock independently causes the system to fail with probability $p$. Let $T$ denote the failure time of the system, and let $N$ be the number of shocks received up to and including time $T$.
>
> (a) Suppose that $N = n$. What is the conditional distribution (name and parameter(s)) of $T$?
>
> (b) Suppose that a failed system is always immediately replaced by a new system. What is the distribution (name and parameter(s)) of the number of replacements that occur during a fixed time interval $[0, t]$?
>
> (c) Suppose that $5$ shocks occur during $[0, t]$. What is the distribution (name and parameter(s)) of the number of replacements during $[0, t]$?
>
> (d) Given that $T = t$, what is the conditional distribution (name and parameter(s)) of $N$?

This is a question from my university's past final exam. I am not too sure if my answers are correct, please verify:

(a) Exponential distribution with rate $p\lambda$

(b) Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$

(c) Binomial distribution ~ $(5,p)$

(d) Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda t$

Comment: Shouldn't your answer to (a) depend on $n$?

Comment: Yeah I think it should be gamma distribution with parameters $n, \lambda$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > (a) Suppose that $N=n$. What is the conditional distribution (name and parameter(s)) of 
> >     $T$?
>
> (a) Exponential distribution with rate $pλ$

*Under the condition* that $N=n$, no sock until the $n$-th cause the system to fail, and so $T$ measures the time until the $n$-th shock; ie, its distribution is that for *the sum of $n$ exponential random variables each with rate $\lambda$*.

> > (b) Suppose that a failed system is always immediately replaced by a new system. What is the distribution (name and parameter(s)) of the number of replacements that occur during a fixed time interval $[0,t]$?
>
> (b) Poisson distribution with parameter $λt$

That is the distribution for the count of shocks within the interval.

We seek the distribution for the count of *failure causing* shocks within the interval.

> > (c) Suppose that $5$ shocks occur during $[0,t]$. What is the distribution (name and parameter(s)) of the number of replacements during $[0,t]$?
>
> (c) Binomial distribution ~ $(5,p)$

$\color{green}\checkmark$ That is the distribution for the count of failure causing shocks among $5$ shocks which occur independently with identical rate $p$.

> > (d) Given that $T=t$, what is the conditional distribution (name and parameter(s)) of $N$?
>
> (d) Poisson distribution with parameter $λt$

At time $T$ the first failure-causing shock has occurred, and $N-1$ counts the shocks which have not caused failure.

What is the distribution for the count of *non-failure-causing* shocks within period $[0,t)$ ?

Comment: So (b) should be Poisson distribution with parameter $p \lambda t$ right?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation of the last question, which is exactly the same question I asked in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3295191/poisson-process-thinning-process-shock-arrival). Why do you not take account of the the failure-causing shock?

Comment: I understood the second question. I answered in my own post.

Comment: Yes, the count for failure-causing shocks in interval $[0,t]$ has a Poisson distribution with rate $p\lambda t$.

Comment: And yes, the reason for not taking it into account is because the two processes are independent, and that the condition is that exactly one of the failure-causing has occurred,